# How to detect in Jenkins Workflow if parameterized build parameter exists or not?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

What is the best way that I can detect if a parameter in a parameterized build exists or not?
The closest solution I found was to do this in groovy:

```
node {
   groovy.lang.Binding myBinding = getBinding()
   boolean mybool = myBinding.hasVariable("STRING_PARAM1")
   echo mybool.toString()
   if (mybool) {
       echo STRING_PARAM1
       echo getProperty("STRING_PARAM1")
   } else {
       echo "STRING_PARAM1 is not defined"
   }

   mybool = myBinding.hasVariable("DID_NOT_DEFINE_THIS")
   if (mybool) {
       echo DID_NOT_DEFINE_THIS
       echo getProperty("DID_NOT_DEFINE_THIS")
   } else {
       echo "DID_NOT_DEFINE_THIS is not defined"
   }
}
```

Is using getBinding() the proper API to do this, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using Pipelines then you have access to the object: params whichs is a Java map, then you can use: containsKey method, i.e:

```
if(params.containsKey("STRING_PARAM1")) {
   echo "STRING_PARAM1 exists as parameter with value ${STRING_PARAM1}"
} else {
   echo "STRING_PARAM1 is not defined"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use try-catch to check for the existence of a parameter:

```
try {
    echo TEST1
    echo 'TEST1 is defined'
} catch (err) {
    echo 'TEST1 is not defined'
}
```

Comment: More specifically, you can catch `MissingPropertyException`.

Answer (score 3):

When you're in Sandbox mode (or via a SCM), you're not allowed to use the getBinding(). At least, that's what I've run into so far.

What I've used so far is following method, in the workflow file, at the top I insert the following:

```
properties([[$class: 'ParametersDefinitionProperty', parameterDefinitions: [[$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'default_value', description: '', name: 'your_parameter']]]])
```

This way your parameter will have a default value, which will be overridden when it is supplied as a build parameter.

Comment: This actually won't work in initial builds: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35698

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `params` variable in the newer versions of Jenkins.

Here is how I read the `PLATFORM` parameter of a parametrized build. It is a String parameter.

```
def platform = params?.PLATFORM?.trim()

stage("checkPlatform") {
  if (platform) {
    echo "Going to build for platform: ${platform}"
    // ...
  } else {
    echo "No platform given. Cancelling build"
    error("No platform given")
  }
}
stage("..."){
    ///...
}
```

There is a tutorial here: https://st-g.de/2016/12/parametrized-jenkins-pipelines

I wrote "newer versions of Jenkins" above. Here is the definition from that tutorial:

> As of workflow-cps version 2.18, a new params global variable provides sane access also on the first run (by returning specified default values).